# Enforce parameters into a google research (Python)

Tags: python

I created a python script that allows me to search on google on a terminal.

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import pprint

searchSubject = input("Research: ")
#What I'm looking for like on a normal google research

api_key = "my_api_key"
cse_id = "my_cse_id"

def google_search(search_term, api_key, cse_id, **kwargs):
    service = build("customsearch", "v1", developerKey=api_key)
    res = service.cse().list(q=search_term, cx=cse_id, **kwargs).execute()
    return res['items']

results = google_search(str(searchSubject), api_key, cse_id, num=10)
for result in results:
    pprint.pprint(result)
```

The thing is, I would like to enforce certain parameters into my research. I am looking for .onion websites. When I type that, I get salad recipes. I would like the research to include explicitly .onion (the `.` is the key word here). I tried to find proper documentations to enforce parameters but didn't find any.

Comment: I think you are looking for results from only the website onion.com, am I right?

Comment: Sadly no. If it was that easy I simply would use the cse_id of the onion.com website. I am looking for websites on the deep web that are documented (mentioned) on websites that I can find on google.

Comment: ok I got it, you want websites who has the top level domain .onion, eg- something.onion. Unfortunately deep web websites are NOT indexed by search engines, so you can't find them on google.

Comment: I do know that .onion websites are not indexed on google. What I am looking for are websites on google who mention .onion websites. For example, I found on google a website called ihavewebsites.com (it's an example) and in that website .onion links were mentioned. But when I type on my tool .onion I get salad recipes. I want to enforce the `.` so that I get the "ihavewebsites.com' whom mention .onion websites ^^

Comment: link:*.onion should do it, won't be much accurate. Also you can try ".onion" (don't remove quotes)

Comment: Also you might find better answers here https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/4619/how-do-i-find-onion-sites